# Somar todos os resultados de uma tabela e separar por dia/mês

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho uma tabela, onde gostaria de somar todos os resultados e separa-los por Dia/Mês.

```
01/Abril   =   3 Resultados;
03/Abril   =   5 Resultados;
02/Maio    =   1 Resultado;
```

A tabela que estou usando.

```
**ID   --   item_data**
01   ||   2018-04-01
02   ||   2018-04-03
03   ||   2018-04-01
04   ||   2018-05-02
05   ||   2018-04-01
06   ||   2018-04-03
07   ||   2018-04-03
08   ||   2018-04-03
09   ||   2018-04-03
```

Comment: Você podia colocar a tabela e as colunas para ajudar o "pessoar" a responder

Answer (score 3):

É necessário utilizar o `group by` para agrupar as datas iguais:

```
select 
    count(*)                            as 'total',
    DATE_FORMAT(item_data,'%m/%d')      as 'data'    
from tabela
group by
DATE_FORMAT(item_data,'%m/%d');
```

**EDIT**

Exemplo com `timestamp`

```
select 
    count(*)                                                    as 'total',
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(item_data_timestamp), '%m/%d')    as 'data'    
from tabela
group by
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(item_data_timestamp), '%m/%d')
```

Comment: Funcionou com o formato datetime do jeito que eu queria, mas eu consigo aplicar para o formato timestamp?

Comment: Consegue sim, basta converter para data e aplicar o `date_format`, adicionei na resposta um exemplo